# Accessing a row in a table based on the td element based on its content

Tags: java, selenium

I am writing selenium code to check the contents of a td elements that matches a specific date.

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            "C://chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    String baseUrl = "http://espn.go.com/nba";
    String endPoint = "/team/schedule/_/name/chi/year/2015/chicago-bulls";

    // launch browser and direct it to the Base URL
    driver.get(baseUrl + endPoint);

    WebElement table_element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".mod-container.mod-table.mod-no-header-footer"));
    List<WebElement> tr_collection = table_element.findElements(By.xpath("div/table/tbody/tr"));
    for (WebElement trElement : tr_collection) {
        List<WebElement> td_collection = trElement.findElements(By.xpath("td"));
        if (td_collection.get(0).getText().equals("Wed, Oct 29")) {
            WebElement tdElement = td_collection.get(2);
            System.out.println(tdElement.getText().split("\\n")[1]);
            break;
        }
    }
    // close browser
    driver.close();
}
```

Here I am getting all the rows of `table` and then checking if the first column has value "Wed, Oct 29", if it matches then fetching the 3rd column value.

Is there a way to directly look for a `td` element whose value matches "Wed, Oct 29"? or a simplified logic for this?

Comment: Can you sum up the Manual Steps you are trying to automate and the relevant HTML?

Comment: @DebanjanB, I updated my question, the lines below the code explains what I am trying to do, can you please check now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the 3rd element, I suppose is the result column, you can use this Xpath:

```
.//td[contains(text(),'Wed, Oct 29')]/following-sibling::td[2]
```

[image]

The condition is the text in the td to obtain a brother of him, in this case the second brother or the 3rd column.

With this Xpaht you obtain the WebElement and after that you could use the `getText` function. This function should return the node text and all the children text too.